# Should I keep this "GlobalConnection" or create connection for every query?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, connection

I have inherited a legacy Delphi application that uses ADO to connect to SQL Server.

The application has a notion of a "Global Connection" -- that is a single connection that it opens at the start, and then keeps open all throughout the running of the application (which can be days, weeks, or longer....)

So my question is this:  Should I keep this way of doing things or should I switch to a "connect-query-disconnect" mode of doing things?  Does it matter?

Switching would be a non-trivial task, but I'll do it if it means better performance, data management, etc.

Comment: Do you have detect a problem by now? What kind of application is it? There's a difference if it's a winforms app with a single user(or a windows service) or a web application.

Comment: I would predict a poorer performance due to the overhead of permanent connect and disconnect.

Comment: It's a client/server application written in Delphi.

Comment: I should add that the app has major DB performance issues.

Comment: One thing that would require multiple ADO connections is if your application is multi-threaded, since an ADO connection cannot be used by two threads.

Comment: When you say "it's a C/S Delphi app", you mean multiple Delphi clients connecting to a single SQL server, right?  Just making sure that there isn't a Delphi service in the middle there.

Comment: @afrazier -- correct.

Comment: @NickHodges, does your app use DB-aware components? If so, then you should be aware of serious network impact such components can have in most scenarios.

Comment: @LightBulb, that depends. If the ADO components are used like connected dataset, data-aware controls can make things worse. If not (TADODataset can mimick much of the core functionality of TClientDataset), the controls doesn't matter that much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, it depends on what you're expecting to get out of it, and what kind of application it is.

There's nothing in particular wrong with using a single long-running connection, as long as the application can gracefully handle disconnections and recover or log/notify when it can't reconnect.

The problem with a connect-query-disconnect setup is that you're adding the overhead of connecting and disconnecting on every query.  That's going to slow things down, and in an interactive GUI application users may notice the additional overhead.  You also have to make sure that authorization is transparently handled if it isn't already.

At the same time, there may be interactive performance gains to be had if you can push all the queries off onto background threads and asynchronously update the GUI.  If contention appears because the queries are serialized, you can migrate to a connection-pool system fairly readily as well and improve things even more.  This has a fairly high complexity cost to it though, so now you're looking to balancing what the gains are compared to the work involved.

Right now, my ultimate response is "if it ain't broke, don't fix it."  Changes along the lines you propose are a lot of work -- how much do the users of this application stand to gain?  Are there other problems to solve that might benefit them more?

Edit: Okay, so it's broke.  Well, slow at least, which is all the same to me.  If you've ruled out problems with the SQL Server itself, and the queries are performing as fast as they can (i.e. DB schema is sane, the right indexes are available, queries aren't completely braindead, server has enough RAM and fast enough I/O, network isn't flaky, etc.), then yes, it's time to find ways to improve the performance of the app itself.

Simply moving to a connect-query-disconnect is going to make things worse, and the more queries you're issuing the bigger the drop off is going to be.  It sounds like you're going to need to rearchitect the app so that you can run fewer queries, run them in the background, cache more aggressively on the client, or some combination of all 3.

Don't forget the making the clients perform better means that server side performance gets more important since it's probably going to be handling a higher load if clients start making multiple connections and issuing multiple queries in parallel.

Answer (score 5):

As mr Frazier told before - the one global connection is not bad *per se*.

If you intend to change, first detect **WHAT** is the problem. Let's see some scenarios:

## 1

Some screens(IOW: an set of 1..n forms to operate in a business entity) are slow. Possible causes:

1. insuficient filtering resulting in a pletora of records being pulled from database without necessity.
2. the number of records are ok, but takes too much to render it. Solution: faster controls or intelligent rendering (ex.: Virtual list views)
3. too much queries each time you open an screen. Possible solutions: use TClientDatasets (or any in-memory dataset) to hold infrequently modified lookup tables. An more sophisticated cache for more extensive tables or opening those datasets in other threads can improve response times.
4. Scrolling on datasets with controls bound can be slow (just to remember, because those little details can be easily forgotten).

## 2

Whole app simply slows down. Checklist:

1. Network cards are ok? An few net cards mal-functioning can wreak havoc even on good structured networks as they create unnecessary noise on the line.
2. [MSSQL DBA HAT ON] The next on the line of attack is SQL Server. Ask the DBA to trace blocks and deadlocks. Register slow queries and work on them speed up. This relate directly to #1.1 and #1.3
3. Detect if some naive developer have done `SELECT` inside transactions. In read committed isolation, it's just overhead, as it'll create more network traffic. Open the query, retrieve the data and close the **dataset**.
4. Review the database schema, if you can.
5. Are any data-bound operations on a bulk of records (let's say, remarking the price of some/majority/all products) being done **on the app**? Make an SP or refactor the operation on an query, it'll be much faster and will reduce the load of the entire server.
6. Extensive operations on a group of records? Learn how to do that operations at once on the server instead of one-by-one record. See an examination of most used alternatives on the [MSSQL MVP Erland Sommarskog's article on array and list on MSSQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html).
7. Beware of queries with `WHERE` like : `WHERE SomeFunction(table1.blabla) = @SomeParam` . Most of time, that ones will not use an index causing to read the entire table to select the desired data. If is a big table.... Indexing on a persisted computed columns can make miracles...[MSSQL HAT OFF]

That's what I can think of without a little more detail... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Database connections are time consuming resources to create and the rule of thumb should be create as little as possible and reuse as much as possible. That's why some other technologies have database connection pools, which are typically established at application/service startup and then kept as long as possible and shared among threads.

From your comment, the application has performances issues, but it's difficult without more details to make any recommendation.

Should try to nail down what is slow - are all queries slow or just some specific ones? 
If just some specific ones is there some correlation.

My 2 cents.